# Why is get_headers returning 404 Not Found for legitimate URI?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, handlebars.js

I have a template using handlebars.js to render the page. Inside an each loop I reference some images stored on S3. Some of the images don't exist yet, so I have a 'no-photo' placeholder I show instead. So when I check the headers to determine whether to show the placeholder, I'm getting a 404 every time, even though some of the images exist and get displayed.

```
{#each listings}}
    <div class="wpbl handlebars">
          <div class="IDX-row-content">
              <!-- content row -->
              <div class="IDX-resultsCol IDX-columnOne">
                  <div class="IDX-resultsPhoto">
                    <?php
                    $image_src = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myS3bucket/{{ln}}_0.jpg';
                    $headers = get_headers($image_src);
                    if($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')
                    {
                        // The image doesn't exist in the DOM
                        $image_src = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/no-photo.png';
                    }
                    ?>
                      <img src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" class="IDX-resultsPhotoImg">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div style="display:none;">
                <?php echo var_dump($headers); ?>
              </div>
 // blah blah remaining code
```

The code all works, as the images that exist do render as expected for each listing. But I'm baffled as to why I get a 404 Not Found return from every image. When I echo the var_dump:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>string(22) "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
  [1]=>string(34) "x-amz-request-id: ADFAC90C00E2830A"
  [2]=>string(88) "x-amz-id-2:PMbIxENYEpzSPENjvaM9nkR7PaxSQoyGreaomHZqA15CXyZ0Rz/qwIfK/jxJgB9GUwqpi4DtkgY="
  [3]=>string(29) "Content-Type: application/xml"
  [4]=>string(35) "Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 18:43:32 GMT"
  [5]=>string(17) "Connection: close"
  [6]=>string(16) "Server: AmazonS3"
}
```

When I inspect the html the image is right there:

[image: screenshot from Web Inspector]

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I am not familiar with the template engine you are using, but is `$image_src` what you think it is, do variables get expanded in single quotes?

Comment: I just tested it and yes, the template variables do expand when inside single-quotes or double-quotes.

Comment: But I think you are on to something, I replaced the {{ln}} in the image string with hard-coded image number and it shows up as expected, with a 200 OK header...

Comment: I'm thinking that the {{ln}} variable is provided by handlebars.js after the php headers have already been returned (empty). I'll likely need to provide a php variable for {{ln}} instead.

Comment: That makes sense, php does not have access to javascript variables.